# JavaScript namespace and calling function from two places

Tags: javascript

I've picked up some JavaScript to work on as follows (very much simplified!)

```
var namespace = {
    init: function (config) {
        // do stuff, all ok so far
    },
    events: function () {
        $('#id').on('click', '.class', function (event) {
                alert('hello')
}
}};
```

What I am trying to figure out is how, from the init: block of code, can I call the code in the click event that does alert('hello')?

I realise moving the alert('hello') into a function would help (so I can call the function from init and click), but how would I define the function in this namespace and call it from two places?

What I'm aiming at, and **guessing** the solution is something like this:

```
var namespace = {
    init: function (config) {
        // do stuff
        hello
    },
    hello: function() {
        alert('hello');
    },
    events: function () {
        $('#id').on('click', '.class', function (event) {
            hello
    }
};
```

I will have to pass event param from click into hello.

I'm still trying to figure out how namespaces work in js... Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: FYI, there's no *namespacing* in Javascript. There are scopes and there are objects and there's `this`, but no namescapes. "Namespacing" in Javascript is purely a pattern you do with objects to put some stuff as properties of objects instead of into the global object.

Comment: `namespace.hello()`

Comment: @JonasW I'm sure I tried your suggestion prior to this question with no luck, but after a weekend and fresh eyes it works fine. Thanks for pointing out what was probably obvious!

Comment: @deceze I understand the concept etc, but your info helps support the question and gives it some more context - thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `this` keyword.

```
var namespace = {
    init: function (config) {
        // do stuff
        this.hello();
    },
    hello: function() {
        alert('hello');
    },
    events: function () {

        $('#id').on('click', '.class', function (event) {
            this.hello();
        }.bind(this));
    }
};
```

Example of how to use it:

```
namespace.init();
namespace.events(); // then do a click on the html where you have the class "class"
```

Comment: `this.hello()` didn't work but for me but `namespace.hello()` as per Jonas W comment did work.

Comment: @bloater depends on how you call `init`.

Comment: @Bloater, I have edited my answer with examples. Check then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the powerful functionality of Javascript - **Closures**. Refer the Closures topic in this [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

```js
var namespace = (function(){

    function hello(){
        alert("hello");
    }
    
    return {
      init: function (config) {
          console.log("called init");
          hello();
          console.log("called hello from init")
      },
      events: function () {
          $('#but').on('click', function (event) {
              hello();
              console.log("called hello from events")
          });
       }
    }
})();

namespace.init();
namespace.events();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="but">Click</button>
```